# What does "intern a show" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is an example:

> The show was ably interned by Kate.

Does it mean Kate was helping to create the show as an intern. 
It was at the end of [Crash Course World History](https://youtu.be/5A_o-nU5s2U).

Comment: I haven't watched this show [nor am I ever likely to] but the questions we see on here generated from it makes it sound like the guy uses language like a shotgun rather than a rifle. He sprays random sound bites rather than uses words with precision. An intern, as you probably know, is someone getting work experience for little or no pay. Presumably poor Kate was working on that show... for little or no pay. Her job description is not 'intern', it might be 'production assistant' or similar - however, Mr shotgun treats the one as the other. I'd hate to work for him ;-)

Comment: This is  a transitive verb created from the noun **intern**, meaning "to act in the role of intern in the production of some work".   It is analogous to "captained" or "manned" or "piloted" or "stewarded".  But as Tetsujin says, an **intern** contributes effort and gets work experience, so the analogous formation is semantically odd.